# Can't start protractor with firefox

Tags: firefox, webdriver, protractor

When I start protractor firefox opens, but my tests does not execute. After a while I get time out Error.  Can you help me where is the problem? (Works fine with chrome).

OS: Windows 8.1 x64

protractor --version
Version 4.0.2

firefox version 48.0

protractor.config.js:

```
exports.config = {
    directConnect: true,
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    specs: ['*.spec.js'],
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:9876',
    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'firefox'
    }
};
```

First i start webdriver:

```
>webdriver-manager start
```

Then in other cmd, I run protractor:

```
>protractor protractor.conf.js
```

Output:

```
X:\e2e>protractor protractor.conf.js
[15:38:25] I/direct - Using FirefoxDriver directly...
[15:38:25] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[15:39:11] E/launcher - Timed out waiting for the WebDriver server at http://127
.0.0.1:55485/hub
[15:39:11] E/launcher - Error: Timed out waiting for the WebDriver server at htt
p://127.0.0.1:55485/hub
    at Error (native)
    at onError (C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_
modules\selenium-webdriver\http\util.js:87:11)
    at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_m
odules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1379:14)
    at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protr
actor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2913:14)
    at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\p
rotractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2896:21)
    at C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\s
elenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2775:27
    at C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\s
elenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:639:7
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:369:9)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.createSession (C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\p
rotractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:329:24)
    at Driver (C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_m
odules\selenium-webdriver\firefox\index.js:386:38)
    at Direct.getNewDriver (C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\prot
ractor\built\driverProviders\direct.js:75:26)
    at Runner.createBrowser (C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pro
tractor\built\runner.js:187:43)
    at C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\runner.j
s:261:30
    at _fulfilled (C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\no
de_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_module
s\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_
modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
    at C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q
\q.js:556:49
    at runSingle (C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\nod
e_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
[15:39:11] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
```

Comment: can you put you code related to browser.get() and an empty  browser opened atleast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox 48 is not yet supported by latest version of protractor , please downgrade your firefox to **47.0.1** and try it would certainly work!

Answer (score 0):

Install the latest version of Firefox and protractor .
Open the command line in admin mode if you have installed Firefox inside of program files to avoid potential access errors .

Use the below mentioned capabilities in your conf.js

```
exports.config = {
  framework: 'jasmine',
  directConnect: false, //Start protractor without start the selenium server using webdriver-manager start. default value is fales
  //This is  only for chrome and firefox and use drivers instead of selenium server

  capabilities: {
      browserName: 'firefox',
      'moz:firefoxOptions': {
            args: ['--verbose'],
            binary: 'C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe'
       //Need to start cmd via admin mode to avoid permission error
        }
},   
    //set to true So each spec will be executed in own browser instance. default value is false
    //restartBrowserBetweenTests: true,
     jasmineNodeOpts: {
    //Jasmine provides only one timeout option  timeout in milliseconds don't add ;
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 180000
     },

  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['src/com/sam/scriptjs/iframes.spec.js']

}
```